# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/internal/common/assertion/AssertParameter

Tags: java, eclipse, rest-assured, jsonpath

I've a Java project and I only need to use json-path library hence I downloaded it `json-path-4.1.0.jar` from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/rest-assured/json-path/4.1.2/. I placed it under one folder say `test` in same eclipse project.

I went to project in eclipse, right click it then `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path` -> `Libraries` -> `Add Jar` and selected `json-path` jar from above `test` folder then clicked on `Apply and Close`. Build project and run a class file which is using `json-path` library but it results into error -

```
FAILED: test
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/internal/common/assertion/AssertParameter
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.createJsonAssertion(JsonPath.java:1014)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.get(JsonPath.java:201)
    at io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.getString(JsonPath.java:352)
    at com.eqtechnologic.framework.TestJsonPath.test(TestJsonPath.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Can someone please help how this can be resolved? I restarted eclipse, rebuilt project several times but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case at least [`rest-assured-common-4.1.0.jar`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/rest-assured/rest-assured-common/4.1.0/) is required to fix the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

See [*JSON Path » 4.1.0*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path/4.1.0), section *Compile Dependencies*.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, you are right! After I added `rest-assured-common-4.1.0.jar`, it gave same error for another - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject`. Looks I'll have to add all compile dependencies as you pointed.